# IP Scheme design for 8 subnets and 255 users

Tags: networking, subnet

Can you be asked a question like design an IP scheme for 8 subnets and 255 users? Or the subnets bits borrowed strictly determines the number of hosts you can get?

Comment: Yes you could, but the answer would be simple.. `192.168.0.0/24`, `192.168.1.0/24`, etc until you have 8 subnets. Keep in mind, the `/24` subnet only provides `253 usable addresses`, so if `255 users` are required, you need a `/23` subnet which provides `510 usable addresses`. Same logic here: `192.168.0.0/23`, `192.168.2.0:23`, etc

Comment: See [this excellent answer](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7117/8499) that is on [networkengineering.se] for how to do IP math. You need to do this in binary, then it becomes obvious. With IPv4, you must subtract two from the number of addresses in a network to get the number of hosts because you cannot use the first (network) or last (broadcast) address in a network.